# call the scope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i have two scope in my modal.rb, so what i am trying to do like

test.rb

```
scope :only_type1, where("test.test_type = ?", TYPE1)
scope :only_type2, where("test.test_type = ?", TYPE2)
```

controller.rb

```
if type
  type = :only_type1
else
  type = :only_type2
end
data = Test.by_phase(id).#(can i use the type here)
```

I mean, can i append that variable depends on that condition? or any other way to do this without replicate that query?

Thanks

Comment: you can pass arguments to scopes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Comment: thanks, i know that but can i store that scope name into type variable and call that at last of this Test.by_phase(id).

Comment: You mean like `data = Test.by_phase(id).send(type)`? However you should use dynamic scope anyway, everything is better if you can avoid using send.

Comment: thanks, might be it will be a stupid question, can i use some thing like 
      Test.by_phase(id).#(type)

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan says you can use a scope with an argument:

```
scope :type, ->(type) { where(test_type: type)}
```

Or if you want just to fix your controller, as BroiSatse says:

```
data = Test.by_phase(id).send(type)
```